# Lattice Diamond Clock Assignment issue with ECP5 Versa

Tags: fpga, lattice

I try to get a Lattice ECP5 Versa Board running but I struggle with the port assignment for my clock as I don't understand what exactly Lattice Diamond is doing. It's the first time I'm working with Diamond but the tutorials and user guides didn't really help.

I've set up a simple project, all I wanna do is let one of the onboard LEDs blink with a 1Hz frequency.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

USE work.config_package.ALL;

ENTITY top_entity IS
  PORT(
    SYSCLK        : IN    std_logic;
    CLKOUT        : OUT   std_logic;
    LED           : OUT   std_logic
  );

END ENTITY top_entity;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF top_entity IS
  SIGNAL clk_i, rst_i, clken_1MHz, clken_1kHz : std_logic;

  COMPONENT ECP5PLL IS
    PORT(CLKI  : IN  std_logic;
         CLKOP : OUT std_logic;
         CLKOS : OUT std_logic
        );
  END COMPONENT ECP5PLL;

  COMPONENT powerup_rst IS
    GENERIC(
      rst_time : IN integer := 5000     --100ms
    );
    PORT(
      clk_i     : IN  std_logic;
      rst_i     : IN  std_logic;
      force_rst : IN  std_logic;
      rst_o     : OUT std_logic;
      rst_n_o   : OUT std_logic
    );
  END COMPONENT powerup_rst;

  COMPONENT clockdivider_const
    GENERIC(
      div_value        : integer;
      reset_on_disable : boolean
    );
    PORT(
      clk_i      : IN  std_logic;
      rst_i      : IN  std_logic;
      enable     : IN  std_logic;
      clk_out_en : OUT std_logic;
      clk_out    : OUT std_logic
    );
  END COMPONENT clockdivider_const;

BEGIN

 -- SOD  <= (OTHERS  => 'Z');

  SOD(0)  <= led;

  ECP5PLL_inst : COMPONENT ECP5PLL
    PORT MAP(
      CLKI  => SYSCLK,
      CLKOP => clk_i,
      CLKOS => open
    );


    -- Reset on power up
  u1_powerup_rst_inst : powerup_rst
    GENERIC MAP(
      rst_time => 50
    )
    PORT MAP(
      clk_i     => clk_i,
      rst_i     => '0',
      force_rst => '0',
      rst_o     => rst_i
    );


  -- Clockdivider for 1MHz clock
  u1_clockdivider_const_inst : clockdivider_const
    GENERIC MAP(
      reset_on_disable => true,
      div_value        => 160_000_000
    )

    PORT MAP(
      clk_i      => clk_i,
      rst_i      => rst_i,
      enable     => '1',
      clk_out    => LED,
      clk_out_en => open
    );
 
END ARCHITECTURE rtl;
```

According to the ECP5 Versa User Guide there's a 100MHz oscillator input at port P3/P4 so my intuition would be to create a pin assignment `SYSCLK -> P3` but my lattice spreadsheet looks as follows (ignore the `FPGA_UART_RX`, `SOD[0]` and `SOD[1]` signals, they have been removed for simplicity).

[image]

So why does Diamond list the PLL ports `CLKI`, `CLKOP` and `CLKOS` and lists the entity port `SYSCLK` as "Nonexistent"?

Comment: Maybe you accidentally set PLL as top module for synthesis?